# How to print the record of Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to echo each object of an array.
My output is this like in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79ZYj.png)

Comment: That is nothing to do with codeigniter, you have to use PHP - first you need to learn `Loop`

Comment: look at the image please

Comment: Please do not add images of text.  Add the text itself to the question as it is much easier to read and work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple foreach should do it.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
      // optionally add a second foreach here
      foreach($value as $k => $v) {
           echo $k . ": " . $v;
      }
}
```

Also, there are no objects here only array values.

Comment: it's showing error Array to string coversion

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r()`. Here is the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

For example :

```
$arr = [
    "abc" => ["Uncertain" => 1, "Agree" => 2, "Disagree" => 3],
    "def" => ["Uncertain" => 1, "Agree" => 2, "Disagree" => 3],
];
print_r($arr);
```

Output will be :

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [Uncertain] => 1
            [Agree] => 2
            [Disagree] => 3
        )

    [def] => Array
        (
            [Uncertain] => 1
            [Agree] => 2
            [Disagree] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: I want to echo each object of an array??
Please look at the image above

Comment: `print_r` will print in that format only. See the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function for this problem for any array

```
<?php
$array=array('a','b','c');
echo stringFromArray($array);

function stringFromArray($array,$depth='') {
  $ret='';
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
      $ret.= "\n".$depth.$key . ": " . stringFromArray($value,$depth."\t");  // add tab character to create indent
    } else { // todo: should check if $value actually is echoable variable type
      $ret.= "\n".$depth.$key . ": " . $value;
    }
  }
  return($ret);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you need to print the result of the survey or report in a view.
Just pass the array to view from controller and loop there. using foreach as mentioned above by @Tonic